# CSS/HTML - Word Spacing in Chrome not working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cpu-word, spacing

So I searched the other threads but didn't find an answer. My issue is kind of odd in my opinion. I am trying to do word spacing of about 10px to 15px for my navigation links. When I test the page locally by just opening the index file it works. But once I upload it to cpanel it doesn't work.

CSS:

```
/* Body and Container Styles */
body {
    background - color: #C8C8C6;
    min - width: 50 % ;
}

container {

    margin - left: auto;
    margin - right: auto;
    width: 100 % ;
    min - width: 1340px;

}

/* Div styles */

div {
    border - radius: 10px;
    overflow: visible;
}


.navigation {

    word - spacing: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    background - color: #66CCFF;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: # FFCC66;
    overflow: visible;
    min - width: 800px;
    min - height: 30px;


}

ul {
    list - style - type: none;
    margin - top: 2px;
    margin - bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    font - size: x - large;
}

li {
    display: inline;

}

.left {
    background - color: #FFCC66;
    border: 2px dashed;
    border - color: #66CCFF;
    margin-top:10px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 500px;
    min-width: 200px;
    float:left;
    overflow: visible;
}

.right{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: # FFCC66;
    border: 2px dashed;
    border - color: #66CCFF;
    margin-top:10px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 250px;
    min-width: 100px;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
}

.middle {    
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background-color: # FFCC66;
    border: 2px dashed;
    border - color: #66CCFF;
    margin-top:10px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    min-height: 250px;
    min-width: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
}



/* footer style */

footer {
    height: 20px;
    background - color: # 66CCFF;
    margin - top: 10px;
    margin - right: 150px;
    margin - bottom: 5px;
    margin - left: 150px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border - color: #FFCC66;
    overflow: visible;
}

footer p {
    margin: auto;
    margin - top: 2px;
    margin - left: 5px;
    font - size: x - small;
    text - align: left;
}


/* Media styles */

embed {
    margin - top: 20px;
}

/* Heading Styles */

h1 {
    text - align: center;
    font - family: Impact,
    Charcoal,
    sans - serif;

}


/* link styles */

a: link {
    text - decoration: none;
}
a: visited {
    color: white;
}
a: hover {
    color: #C8C8C6;
}


/* Paragraph and Text styles */

p {
    text - align: center;
}

/* Scrollbar */

::-webkit - scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit - scrollbar - track {
    -webkit - box - shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(200, 200, 198, 1);
    border - radius: 7px;
}

::-webkit - scrollbar - thumb {
    border - radius: 7px; - webkit - box - shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(71, 211, 255, 1);
}
```

Comment: your question is bit vague!!!! can you please explain it again?

Comment: Yes sorry. So I have the navigation links set up to have 15px spaces between each word.

.navigation{

word-spacing: 15px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #66CCFF;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: 150px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 150px;
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #FFCC66;
overflow: visible;
min-width: 800px;
min-height: 30px;

But it isn't working basically. For some reason when I view it in chrome it works. But if I load it to cpanel then it doesn't work. Let me post screenshots.

Comment: This is what it looks like when I actually upload it:
http://i39.tinypic.com/f51fn.png
This is what it looks like before I upload it :
http://i42.tinypic.com/wkgs29.png

Comment: It's the "load it to cpanel" part that is not making so much sense. Once you upload it, what URL are you using to view the page?

Comment: the URL is melissaj.cityuseattle.net ( and before you ask, no this actually isn't homework they gave me an account for a class and why not use it? xD )

Comment: i beleive what you are trying to say is that you need some spacing for your navigations links i.e(Home,Event etc) and you are referring them as "spacing between the words".......

Comment: Yes sorry. I wasn't quite sure how to explain it.

Comment: did you consider of margin-left for your list tag..... you can set some margin say 10px for your list tag and check it out

Comment: Your page is missing its `<html>` starting tag for a start (after the doctype declaration,) and ... maybe try changing it to `<!DOCTYPE html>` for the doctype declaration. Then can you re-upload and we'll look again?

Comment: ^ Thanks for pointing that out. So using margin-left worked but I don't understand why using word-spacing: 15px; didn't work. It worked in IE and it worked when just opened on my computer and not uploaded to cpanel. I posted links to pictures of what I am talking about in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you're using the `<center>` element. This element is obsolete. You should use CSS to determine its position (you could put `text-align: center;` on `.navigation`.) Don't use obsolete elements. Once you do that, the `word-spacing` works fine.

http://validator.w3.org/ and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ help to check your page for syntax errors humans can easily miss. They are an invaluable tool for people developing websites.

Comment: Ok I tried that but for some reason it isn't working. I am going to try on a different computer using the same browser.

Comment: I'm looking at your page and it's working fine. Are you cached? This is rule #1 for developing websites: clear the cache.

Comment: Thank you for the links! Unfortunately i checked on another computer and it is the same thing. Maybe this is an issue with Cpanel? It seems strange that it works in IE. I cleared the cache and same issue. It works if you just open it in chrome from your computer. But once the file is uploaded it doesnt work . So far the margin left suggestion is the only one that works

Comment: It's most definitely working: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rwnzsydazw398q/screenshot-word-spacing.png this is your site, I edited the `word-spacing` value using Inspector to make sure it was working. Chrome & FF are fine.

Comment: ^ Then wtf is going on with my computers ): Both IE and Firefox work but not chrome. Are there any other errors in my code?

Comment: Is your Chrome up to date? Validator is picking up a few extra errors, but none that would explain the `word-spacing` not working. Also, you definitely cleared your cache?

Comment: I just checked and chrome is up to date and yes I cleared the cache and then closed/reopened the browser. I tested it in chrome on both my laptop and Surface. So im starting to feel like maybe this is an issue with cpanel because it doesn't make sense that it would work before I upload it and then not work.

Comment: If it was a cpanel issue then it wouldn't work for me either. It's definitely a browser issue localised to you. Try changing some link `colour`s or `background-color`s of some elements, re-upload, and view it in your browser. If you don't see changes, you're still cached.

Comment: If you go to melissaj.cityuseattle.net in chrome on your computer it works? I changed the background color to blue and it worked so im not cached. If it is working for you then there is something weird going on for me.

Comment: Yep. Here, I've copied your code from your site into a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SD6p9/ and increased the `word-spacing` value. Definitely working. IE, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera 12, Opera 16 ...

Comment: Alright, something weird on my end then. Thank you for the help you are awesome (: !